# Getting response of a form request using scrapy

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to send a form request. The data retrieval works in two ways in the browser:

1. The form is filled in this [page](http://namis.gov.np/pages/market/marketPriceForm)
2. Form request is sent to this [link](http://namis.gov.np/site/pages/ajax_priceList).

The response is used to display a data table and a chart in the same page where the form is filled.

Here's the snippet of my spider,

```
class NamisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "namis-spider"
    form_url = 'http://namis.gov.np/pages/market/marketPriceForm/'
    request_url = 'http://namis.gov.np/site/pages/ajax_priceList/'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.form_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('input[name="csrf_appcore"]::attr(value)').get()
        data = {
            'csrf_appcore': token,
            'market': '1',
            'category': '1',
            'commodity': '104',
            'date_from': '2075-01-01',
            'date_to': '2076-11-21',
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.request_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_market_price)

    def parse_market_price(self, response):
        print(response)
```

The response received in the browser after submitting the form is shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9TYS.png). But I'm unable to replicate this using scrapy. The response I get using scrapy is

```
<200 http://namis.gov.np/site/pages/ajax_priceList/>
```

But I'd like to receive the json response that is received by the browser.

P.S.: The dates are based on Vikram Samvat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing header for X-Requested-With.

`

```
import scrapy
import json

class NamisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "namis-spider"
    form_url = 'http://namis.gov.np/pages/market/marketPriceForm/'
    request_url = 'http://namis.gov.np/site/pages/ajax_priceList/'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.form_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('input[name="csrf_appcore"]::attr(value)').get()

        data = {
            'csrf_appcore': token,
            'market': '1',
            'category': '1',
            'commodity': '104',
            'date_from': '2076-11-21',
            'date_to': '2076-11-21',
        }
        headers = {
            "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.request_url, headers=headers, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_market_price)

    def parse_market_price(self, response):
        unicoded_response = response.body_as_unicode()
        json_response = json.loads(unicoded_response)
        print('json---->',json_response)
        print(json_response['status'])
        print(json_response['data'])
```

`